# How to mix Ruby and strings in slim?

Tags: ruby, slim-lang

Say I have an h1 where I want to welcome a user with a link, so I do this:

```
h1
  | Hello user!
```

But if I want to add a link:

```
h1
  | Hello user, = link_to 'Click here', '#'
```

What is the correct approach in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put it on the next line

```
h1
  | Hello user, 
  = link_to 'Click here', '#'
```